# php date Call to a member function setTime() on a non-object

Tags: php

I am trying to change the hour in my DateTime, and I'm doing it right how the [docs](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.settime.php) say. However there must be something I'm not understanding because when calling that function I'm getting this error `Call to a member function setTime() on a non-object`.

This is my code:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date_in_secs = strtotime($date);
$new_date = $date_in_secs + $delivery_duration + $distribution_time;

$date = date('l d F H:i Y', $new_date);

if (intval(date('H', $new_date)) > 21 || intval(date('H', $new_date)) < 8) {
    $date->setTime(8, 0, 0);
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

Any clue on how I can change my date hour and add one day?

Comment: You've got your strings (`date()` return) and objects (`new DateTime()` mixed up).

Comment: what do you mean? what should I change?

Comment: $date->setTime(8,0,0);

Comment: `$date_in_secs = strtotime` is BEYOND pointless. `$date_in_secs = time()`, without forcing PHP to waste a ton of cpu cycles taking a unix time stamp, converting it to a string, then converting that string back into the exact same timestamp it started out as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the contents/type of `$delivery_duration` and `$distribution_time`?

Also why are you doing this?

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Convert DateTime to String
$date_in_secs = strtotime($date); // Convert String to Timestamp
```

Why not just use DateTime? Much cleaner...

```
$date = new DateTime;
$date->modify('+200 seconds'); // Increase with 200 seconds from $delivery_duration for example

if (intval($date->format('H')) > 21 || intval($date->format('H')) < 8) {
    $date->setTime(8); // Set Hour to 8
    $date->modify('+1 day'); // Increase day by 1
}

$dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I need to transform the date into a timestamp in order to addup seconds, notice the line `$new_date = $date_in_secs + $delivery_duration + $distribution_time;`

Comment: Just add it to the `DateTime` using http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php or http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php. Change the `$delivery_duration` and `$distribution_time` to just seconds.

Comment: and then I am forced to use `strtrotime` again to get the hours

Comment: I don't see why. I just updated the answer to almost match yours. You now only need to find a way to get `$delivery_duration` and `$distribution_time` in seconds and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc :

> public DateTime DateTime::setTime ( int $hour , int $minute [, int
>   $second = 0 ] )

You are putting a string when this is waiting for int separed by commas try this :

`$date->setTime(8,0,0');`

Comment: When I copy the code in my server I don't have any error and $date = Thursday 27 November 19:10 2014

Comment: I am getting `Call to a member function setTime() on a non-object`

Comment: Then sorry i don't think I can help to with this problem because this snippet of code is working for me maybe the problem isn't in those line.

Comment: yes it is exactly in the `setTime` call because the block is wrapped in a try-catch block and I am getting the error `Call to a member function setTime() on a non-object`

Comment: You get the error because your are calling a `DateTime` method on a `String`... Before the if statement you are setting `$date = date('l d F H:i Y', $new_date);` which outputs a `String`.